# Optimal portfolio construction questions

Tags: risk-management

I am working on a paper that tries to build an optimal portfolio to hedge various risks (mainly interest rate risk). I have never done this before. Which software program should I use to create an optimal portfolio simulation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too broad, seems to be missing basic knowledge...